# How does one ask the court to recuse an attorney due to a perceived conflict of interest?

Tags: legal-terms, process, legal-concepts

Is there a legal principle or process that can be used to ask a court in the US - either at the time of filing or during a legal proceeding - to consider recusing an attorney from the opposing side due to a perceived conflict of interest?

What is the name(s) of the process or principle? (So individual state codes can be referred to).

Comment: Jurisdiction please?

Comment: @cpast, as in civil or criminal, or country? (I'm a newby here)

Comment: Country, or subnational jurisdiction if you have it (e.g. US state)

Comment: @cpast, USA....

Comment: Any particular state you're interested in?

Comment: Is there a name of the principle so I can check state codes?

Comment: You can move to disqualify an attorney due to the attorneys knowledge of confidential information. For example say an attorney A used to work for law firm B. And in this law firm he could of heard confidential information about client C. If this attorney quits his job and represents a client suing client C, he could be disqualified due to his prior knowledge of confidential information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't normally ask the court to "recuse" an attorney, because "recusal" is normally restricted to the *judge* leaving the case. The more common term is moving to disqualify opposing counsel.